# Is there a way to keep Spyder's Window Layout when changing environment?

Tags: spyder

The Window Layout changes to `Spyder Default layout` every time I change the virtual environment.
(I'm using python 3.7.10, conda 4.12.0, and Spyder 5.0.5 on Windows 10.)

Is there a way to keep the same layout (e.g., Matlab layout) regardless of the environment?

Comment: Do you have different versions of Spyder in your virtual environments?

Comment: I'm relatively new to Spyder and I'm not sure if I have different versions in my virtual environments (I only see Spyder 5.0.5 when I check `Help > About Spyder`, but could I have different Spyder 5.0.5 in different environments?). Could you let me know if there's a way to check it?